# ListCorrelate vDSP equivalent for convolution of {{a,b,c},{d,e,f}} and {{g,h,i},{j,k,i},{l,m,n}}

Tags: c, xcode, wolfram-mathematica, accelerate-framework, vdsp

If I ListCorrelate two list of real doubles

```js
{{a,b,c},{d,e,f}}
{{g,h,i},{j,k,l},{m,n,o}}
```

in Mathematica I get

```js
{{a*g + b*h + c*i + d*j + e*k + f*l},{a*j + b*k + c*l + d*m + e*n + f*o}}
```

Can anyone tell me the equivalent function in Apple's vDSP for c?
Thanks

Comment: I presume the second list should be `{{g,h,i},{j,k,l},{m,n,o}}`?

Answer (score 3):

The specific case you show can be performed with `vDSP_desampD(B, 3, A, C, 2, 6)`, where A is a pointer to the start of your first list, B is a pointer to the start of the second list, and C is a pointer to space for the output.  The second parameter, 3, is the number of elements in each row/sub-list in B. The fifth parameter, 2, is the number of output elements desired. The last parameter 6, is the number of elements in A.